# How to disable Comcast mistyped address page?

Tags: dns, search, isp, address-bar

I upgraded my Firefox to v7 (I am on Ubuntu if this matters). Before, I could type in the address bar "ebay" or "gmail" for example, and it would take me to those sites. After I upgraded, it redirects to Comcast's (my ISP) search page...

How do I restore the previous behavior?

Comment: Disclaimer: Title was edited to reflect the OP’s _[actual](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/171857)_ problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Firefox. It's your ISP violating the DNS standard. Go to https://dns-opt-out.comcast.net/ to revert normal behavior.

Comment: I don't understand. This should be voted up higher than the other answers which don't answer correctly.

Comment: Another option, in case the opt-out goes away, or you end up with another ISP that uses the same tricks, is to use a third-party DNS server, such as OpenDNS or Google Public DNS.

Comment: @Stephanie OpenDNS does hijacking too.

Comment: Scratch OpenDNS then, sorry, Level3 (209.244.0.3 / 209.244.0.4) is another hijack-free (at least at this time) option.

Answer (score 5):

Your question indicates you want to be able to search in the address bar like Chrome. The functionality I am proposing doesn't take you directly to the site but instead searches Google for the typed keywords. I don't know if there is a better way to do it in FF7 but here is how I did it before:

1. Navigate to `about:config` in the address bar;
2. Filter for `keyword.URL` and change it to `http://www.google.com/?hl=en&source=hp&q=`;

To navigate based on your browsing history and bookmarks in the address bar, go to **Tools -> Options -> Privacy** and in the Location Bar section select **History & Bookmarks**. When this is enabled and you have bookmarked or visited SO in the past, for instance, you'll get a suggestion drop-down with the SO website as one of the suggestions.

Comment: I think @kinokijuf's answer is what the asker was looking for.

Comment: It would be lovely if people explained their down votes.

Comment: The widget is a plugin for Wordpress called Shareaholic. Just stay curious, if you come across something that interests you and you don't know it, research, learn, use, etc. As far as ettiqute goes, you should probably take a look at this page: http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-down

Comment: And I see your point. Considering that you've put a lot of effort in the answer, it didn't deserve a downvote. If I thought some other answer was better, then I should have upvoted it and left it at.

Comment: Where did my comments go?

Comment: I haven't a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: This solution doesn't take you directly to the site.

- Click the Firefox Search Bar dropdown arrow and then *Manage Search Engines*

[image: Firefox Manage Search Engines]

- Select Google from the list and click the **Edit Keyword** button
- Enter "g", then click **OK**

Now you can search from the Firefox address bar by typing the letter "g", followed by a space, followed by your search term.

For example, `g your-search-term-here`. The hotkey `CTRL+L` moves your cursor directly to the Address Bar.

As an alternative, you can just press the hotkey `CTRL+K` to move your cursor directly to the Firefox Search Bar.

Hope that helps!